# Get row and column of excel cell from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

When I search through an Excel file from powershell, I want to get the row and column of the cell with a specific content.

To do so, I have the following code:

```
[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
$e = new-object -com excel.application
$book = $e.Workbooks.Open("C:\tmp\deeg.xlsx")
$sheet = $book.WorkSheets.item(1)
$Cell = $sheet.range("A1:Z8").find("deeg")
Write-Host "Line: " $Cell.rows
$a = read-host 'Press any key'
```

The method 'Rows' does not seem to exist... How can I the the row number and column number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every cell-object has a address()-Method

```
$cell.address($false,$false)
```

gives back the cell-address eg. A5. The switches ($false,$false) calls an relative cell-address (so, not $A$5).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to convert this to a numerical value, like A5 = (1,5) ? This way it can be used in the Cells.item(row, col) method...

Comment: Well, it even has the properties row and column.

Comment: Damn, didn't even see that... Thanks!